# Why do many Republicans seem to minimize Russian invasion of Ukraine?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, republican-party

After Russia invaded Ukraine 2 months ago it has become increasingly clear how horrendous the invasion is, with bombing of civilian targets, executions of civilians (including children), rapes, plunder, leveling entire cities to the ground, etc. The effects extend beyond Ukraine: Poland is overwhelmed with millions of refugees, and at some point Russia threatened use of nuclear weapons, which could lead to WWIII, although they backpedaled on that later.

It would seem that such evens are beyond partisanship. Whatever your beef is with your disagreeable neighbor, if you both see a murder being committed in front of your houses you both call 911 with the same message. And when the cops arrive, and you see the neighbor you hate telling the cop what you both saw, you don't start contradicting him just for spite, you don't say to the cop: "Year, I saw a shooting, but come on, why are you paying attention to this? Somebody trespassed on my property last week, and I've heard a pizza was stolen from a store down the street, why don't you investigate that instead? Also, my brother told me that the shooter is a good buddy of his."

However, as soon as Biden woke up and started to act (which took a while), several conservative talk show hosts and social media channels started minimizing the war. "Why are we sending aid to Ukraine rather than securing our own borders?" - this kind of BS. [Tucker Carlson in particular.](https://www.foxnews.com/search-results/search?q=ukraine%20tucker)

And this point of view, which is almost "let Russian fascists take over Europe, it's not our business", is not consistent with the traditional Republican views on American role in the World and on US military. US under Bush-senior didn't hesitate facing Saddam when Saddam invaded Kuwait in 90s; add numerous other examples. Traditional Republican viewpoint: "you see evil - you confront evil." But not this time; to spite Biden's administration, or for some other reasons I don't understand, the current viewpoint seems to be "you see evil - you notice that your political opponent sees the evil, so you pretend not to see that evil is evil."

Why is that happening? Pure partisanship or something else?

Comment: I think this kind of comment discussion is better suited for [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134420/ukrainian-conflict-2022), or in case of disputed statements: [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Short answer: In 1988 when Bush Sr. was President, the idea of America as "the world's police" was a valid one.  The National Debt was 2.6T, 50% of GDP, which was a "reasonable" number.  After the events of 9/11 and the neverending wars in the Middle East, American politicians as a whole, and particularly Republicans, have decided that interventionism is not a great idea and the "world police" image is not a good one to have.  Combined with the fact that the national debt today is 124% of GDP, and America simply can't afford more wars.

Comment: Not sure the general argument of the question is valid.  [Some polls show relatively high convergence between Reps and Dems that Russia is aggressing Ukraine](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2022/03/10/public-opinion-ukraine-democracy/).  Note that it is different, for a Rep, to think Russia is aggressing than thinking that also means Biden is "doing the right thing".  In any case this seems more a question about how *some specific Republicans* with influence (Tucker Carlson among others) come to their views than a question about *many Republicans*.

Comment: The close reason is incorrect: *"Questions asking for the internal motivations of people, how specific individuals would behave in hypothetical situations or predictions for future events are off-topic, because answers would be based on speculation and their correctness could not be verified with sources available to the public."* The OP is asking a Q that can be answered with objective facts and not speculation, as well as using sources available to the public. The fact that *you* cannot answer it does not mean anyone cannot. VTR.

Comment: @Rusi The question says "*many* Republicans", not "*all* Republicans". One counterexample is not enough to disprove the premise of the question.

Comment: Are those supposed to be more counterexamples? Because they look like examples.

Comment: You gotta give it to Tucker Carlson on a certain kind of consistency though. He doesn't want to help Israel much either. He recently had Vivek over and they bloviated about that. They pat each other on the back feeling victimized that "isolationism has become the new racism". https://youtu.be/16RnsQ__o8g?t=1183

Answer (score 0):

The GOP has not yet coalesced around a narrative for why they dislike the Ukrainian side of this conflict, despite having more than two months to think of one. Ideas that have been floated around so far have been:

1. Isolationism.
2. Utilizing existing Hunter Biden conspiracy theories or just general theories of corruption to tie President Biden to the Ukrainian regime.
3. A vaguely-defined fear that President Biden will remove border patrol agents/soldiers from our southern border to fight in Ukraine.
4. Russia is extremely powerful, and will economically punish the US for standing up to it.
5. Buying into Russian propaganda that the Ukrainian people 'deserve' to become a part of a reimagined Soviet bloc superstate.
6. Ukraine somehow provoked Russia, and therefore deserves the attack it received in return.
7. This is a ploy by the Left to reduce US oil consumption.
8. This is a ploy by the Left to cripple right-wing dissent by subjecting them to hyperinflation.
9. This is part of the gay agenda, punishing a country (Russia) for having traditional ideas about men, women and marriage.
10. The 'Ukrainian biological warfare labs' claim by Russia is true.
11. Obama had a hand in toppling the previous Ukrainian regime and hand-picked the current regime, so they must be bad.

Comment: This answer is literally all speculation... And additionally appears to be biased based on the language.

Comment: Until such time as the GOP comes together to (hopefully) create a cogent narrative to back up their stance, all we have are the opinions stated by their various members.

Comment: It seems that number 4. will soon be exposed as it is not really the case

Comment: @Carduus all this says is that a bunch of different people have a bunch of different reasons for their stance and the only thing in common from your biased sample set is that they are members of the GOP, suggesting that their opinion has nothing to do with the GOP. After all, as you stated the GOP has no official stance, just party members with their own opinions, which they are entitled to have.

Comment: @uberhaxed This answer is not speculation, it's a non-speculative report of another  group's speculation (which the question was about).

Comment: The fact that all of the Republicans support Russia but none of them can come up with a good reason is a very strong indicator that they are working backwards from their desired conclusion.

Comment: @user253751 I don't think it's "all of them." But there are some prominent ones. There are those who do not. 2 of the last 3 Republican Presidential nominees viewed Russia's policies as being at odds with the US. The assessment that there is no unified party platform, which leans one way or another, is probably accurate

Comment: You have definitely missed some: 12. The Democrats are against it, so we must be for it 13. Russia was a considerable help in getting the last Republican President elected.